# How can I create a box based on 2 separate pivot points?

Tags: pine-script

How can I create a box based on 2 separate pivot points? For example: create a box with the high as a pivot high, and the low as the previous pivot low? I'm been scratching my head for 3 days. Please excuse me as I don't know all the functions yet. Any help, would be very very much appreciated!

Comment: How do you detect the pivots? Are you able to figure out their x positions? Show us your code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hello vitruvius, I'm brand new to coding Pine, but am trying to learn as fast as possible. I've basically borrowed the code from the "Pivot Points High Low" indicator, and am playing around with it to try and arrive to what I'm asking. I'm NOT asking for the full code or even a line of code, I'm just asking if there is some specific function or math that can arrive to this point, if so, a hint would be greatly appreciated. I've looked through pretty much every "pivot -based" indicator on TV with a public script and can't seem to find one that has achieved similar results.

Comment: Not sure how to add the code as you're only allowed so many characters? I'm using the ta.pivothigh and ta.pivotlow to detect the points of interest, but not sure how to get a box from the last pivot high, to the previous pivot low.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ta.pivotlow()` and `ta.pivothigh()` to get the pivot points. You should know that there will be a delay of `rightbars` while detecting the pivots. So you should account for this when drawing your box.

Then create a box with the `var` keyword. This way, you don't need to create a new box again and again. Just modify its coordinates when there is a new pivot point.

Here is an example for you:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
bars_left = 5
bars_right = 2

pivot_low = ta.pivotlow(bars_left, bars_right)
pivot_high = ta.pivothigh(bars_left, bars_right)

var float low_price = na
var float high_price = na

low_price := pivot_low ? pivot_low : low_price
high_price := pivot_high ? pivot_high : high_price

plot(low_price, "Pivot Low", color.red, 1, plot.style_circles, offset=-bars_right)
plot(high_price, "Pivot High", color.green, 1, plot.style_circles, offset=-bars_right)

var my_box = box.new(na, na, na, na, na, bgcolor=color.new(color.yellow, 85))

if (pivot_low)  // New pivot low -> Update bottom
    box.set_bottom(my_box, pivot_low)
    box.set_left(my_box, bar_index-bars_right)

if (pivot_high)  // New pivot high -> Update top
    box.set_top(my_box, pivot_high)
    box.set_left(my_box, bar_index-bars_right)

box.set_right(my_box, bar_index)
```

[image]

Comment: I couldn't be thankful enough! Thank you kindly